# How to create new dictionary by selecting particular keys using fromkey() in python Dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary-comprehension, fromkeys

I created the dictionary named as Colors.

```
Colors = {'col1': 'Red', 'col2': 'Orange', 'col3': 'Yellow', 'col4': 'Yellow'}
```

Q) Create a new Dictionary object `colors_new` from the colors Dictionary, having the keys col1 and col2 (Instruction – Use the `fromkeys()` method)? is it possible to use `fromkeys()`?

**My coding is :**

Colors = {'col1': 'Red', 'col2': 'Orange', 'col3': 'Yellow', 'col4': 'Yellow'}

```
print(Colors)

Col={ }

Colors_new={ }

print(Colors_new)

Colors_new = dict.fromkeys(Colors.keys())

print(Colors_new)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
{'col1': 'Red', 'col2': 'Orange', 'col3': 'Yellow', 'col4': 'Yellow'}
{}
{'col1': None, 'col2': None, 'col3': None, 'col4': None}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. It seems a program assignment. What have you done till now? Show us your attempts and then we can start from them

Comment: I assume you want something like colors_new = dict.fromkeys(colors.keys())

Comment: I need only col1 and col2 in my Colors_new

Answer (score 1):

Yes this is indeed possible.

```
colors_new = dict.fromkeys(Colors.keys()[:2])
```

Comment: Nope. I need only col1 and col2.

Comment: while using dictionary slicing, i got error as follows .. .. ..                                                TypeError: 'dict_keys' object is not subscriptable

Answer (score 0):

Is this maybe what you want?

```
Colors = {'col1': 'Red', 'col2': 'Orange', 'col3': 'Yellow', 'col4': 'Yellow'}
print(Colors)
Col={ }
Colors_new={ }
print(Colors_new)
# if you want the new dictionary with only the keys
Colors_new = dict.fromkeys([k for k in Colors.keys() if k in ["col1", "col2"]])
print(Colors_new)
# if you want the new dictionary with keys and values
Colors_new = {k:v for k,v in Colors.items() if k in ["col1", "col2"]}
print(Colors_new)
```

Comment: Good work . Tanq. One more thing i need to clarify is... is it possible to create new dictionary without "none", while using fromkeys() .